# AngularJS- how to display a button in a table cell?

Tags: html, angularjs, button

I recently took over the development of an AngularJS application created by my company, and am currently trying to add a button to a cell in a table, which the user will be able to use as a navigation button, and set the location it directs you to as any one of the user's custom pages.

In the table directive, I have added the following code:

```
.directive('appTable', function(fxTag) {
    return {
        ...
        template: '...',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $compile, Global, fxEvent, fxSearch, NotifyMgr) {
            ...
            var goToPageBtnTmpl = $compile(
                '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="goToPage(target)"' +
                '<class="btn btn-xs btn-brand">Go to Page</a>'
            );
            console.log("goToPageBtnTmpl defined: ", goToPageBtnTmpl);
            ...
            var goToPage = function(target) {
                // Code to navigate to the page set by the user
                console.log("goToPage button added: ");
            };
            ...
        }
    }
})
```

and in ctrl.js, there is a `toWidgetObj()` function, which creates a widget based on the details that the user selects/ enters on a form:

```
}).controller('WidgetPickerCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, fxTag, gPresets, appWidget, appUI, pagesPresets) {
    ...
    function toWidgetObj() {
        ...
        var widgetObj = {
            name: $scope.widget.name,
            label: $scope.widget.label,
            attr: angular.copy($scope.widget)
        };

        switch(widgetObj.name) {
            case 'app-table':
                ...
                angular.forEach(widgetObj.table.rows, function(row) {
                    if(row.length > 0) {
                        reducedRows.push(row.map(
                            function(tag) {
                                if(tag.isTag) {
                                    return {tag: tag.tag, nounit: tag.nounit};
                                }
                                if(tag.isBtn) {
                                    var goToPageBtnTmpl = $compile(
                                        '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click=goToPage(target)"' + 'class= "btn btn-xs btn-brand">Go to page</a>'
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        ));
                    }
                });
                ...
                break;
            ...
        }
        ...
        return widgetObj;
    }
    ...
});
```

When I currently click the 'Edit widget' button on a table widget, the 'Edit Widget dialog is opened, and I add a button to a cell in the table. When I then click the 'Preview' button, to update the widget with the changes I have entered in the dialog, I see the print statement from the `directive` displayed:

> goToPageBtnTmpl defined: publicLinkFn(scope, cloneConnectFn, transcludeControllers, parentBoundTranscludeFn){
>           assertArg(scope, 'scope');

and I am expecting the table to show a the button that has been compiled by the line:

```
var goToPageBtnTmpl = $compile(
    '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="goToPage(target)"' +
    'class = "btn btn-xs btn-brand">Go to page</a>'
)
```

that will take the user to the page whose address I specified in the input on the dialog.

But what I actually see when I click 'Preview' is the table displayed, and the cell where the button should be displayed is actually showing the link that I typed (i.e. the address of the page I am expecting it to take the user to when clicked).

My debug in the console is stating that the button has been added successfully:

> Tag is a button:
>
> {tag: "pages/userpage1", isTag: false, isBtn: true, nounit: false, units: undefined}
>   isBtn
>   :
>   true
>   isTag
>   :
>   false
>   nounit
>   :
>   false
>   tag
>   :
>   "pages/userpage1"
>   units
>   :
>   undefined

but I don't actually see the button displayed on the page.

Anyone have any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit**

So, as I've looked into this further, I think I may have found the reason that the button is not displayed: the code where the button is compiled is written in the `table` directive's `controller` function:

```
.directive('appTable', function(fxTag) {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function(...) {
            ...
            var gotToPageBtnTmpl = $compile(
                ...
            );
```

So this is run when the page first loads. However, I am trying to add the button to the table manually, after the page has already loaded, and the code I'm using to do this is written later in the same `controller` function:

```
            if(!$scope.noTagAlarm()) {
                angular.forEach($scope.config.columns, function(col) {
                    ...
                    if(col.header.startsWith(":")) {
                        angular.forEach($scope.config.rows, function(row) {
                            col.template = function(value, row, metadata) {
                                goToPageBtnTmpl(value);
                            }
                        })
                    }else{
                        console.log("column doesn't start with ':' ");
                    }
                    ...
                });
            }
```

My thought is that since this code is written in the directive's `controller` function, it is probably only run when the page is first loaded, and not when I edit the widget using my 'edit widget' dialog, so the HTML is not rendered.

Would that be the case? If so, how can I reload the widget after editing it without refreshing the whole page? Or, if not, what am I actually doing wrong here?

Comment: Use Chrome Developer tool (Inspect Element) and see if the anchor tag has been rendered properly. I see that there is no space between ng-click="goToPage(target)" and class = "". This might be an issue, not sure though

Comment: I tried inspecting it, but the widget is being updated every few seconds- and every time it is, the console is refreshed, so I can't actually see what's there in time...

Comment: Please include the code where you link the compiled element to the desired scope and then append it to the desired element.

Comment: I'm not sure how/ where I should be doing that?

Comment: I've edited my OP to show why I think the button is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the function used in the `col.template` needed to return the button I wanted to create:

```
col.template = function(value, row, metadata) {
    return [
        umWidget.getBtnTmpl(
            $scope.$new(true),
            goToPage,
            value,
            value)
    ];
}
```

I defined the `getBtnTmpl()` function in Widget/service.js with:

```
function getBtnTmpl(scope, fn, target, title) {
    scope.fn = fn;
    scope.target = target
    var pageTitle = title.split('/');
    scope.title = pageTitle[1];

    return btnTmpl(scope);
}
```

and set `btnTmpl` as a global variable in Widget/service.js with:

```
var btnTmpl = $compile(
    '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="fn(target)"' +
    'class="btn btn-xs btn-brand">{{title}}</a>'
);
```